# Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '/node_modules/classnames/index.js?v=caf6ac94' does not provide an export named 'default'

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

Using this design system https://react.lightningdesignsystem.com/ in a react app built with vite.

When I try using the es6 modules import statement

```
import BrandBand from '@salesforce/design-system-react/components/brand-band';
```

It throws the following error in the console, and doesnt render the component:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '/node_modules/classnames/index.js?v=caf6ac94' does not provide an export named 'default'
```

Note that, I have included   `"type": "module",` in package.json.

What could be the issue for not being able to use the first syntax?

If I use the commonjs way, mentioned [here](https://react.lightningdesignsystem.com/getting-started/#:%7E:text=Quick%20Setup%20(CommonJS)), it works

```
import {BrandBand} from '@salesforce/design-system-react/';
```

but the es6 module syntax doesnt work

Comment: Did you set up your babel presets correctly?